# How does java.util.Arrays.asList(T...) work?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, arraylist, variadic-functions

It seems to be a silly question at the first sight, but I found that the mechanism isn't trivial. The implementation from `JDK 8` (copied from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.asList%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)) is just a few lines:

```
@SafeVarargs
@SuppressWarnings("varargs")
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
    return new ArrayList<>(a);
}
```

The point is that there are only 3 constructors in `ArrayList`:

- one doesn't take any parameter
- one takes an `int` (the initial capacity)
- one takes a `Collection` (the elements) as shown below (copied from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.%3Cinit%3E%28java.util.Collection%29)):

```
public class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
    implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
{

    // ...

    transient Object[] elementData; // non-private to simplify nested class access

    private int size;

    // ...

    public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        elementData = c.toArray();
        size = elementData.length;
        // c.toArray might (incorrectly) not return Object[] (see 6260652)
        if (elementData.getClass() != Object[].class)
            elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, Object[].class);

    }

    // ...

}
```

Since the only possibility is that the 3rd constructor is called, it seems that the parameter `a` (the generic vararg) is somehow "casted" to a `Collection`. But as far as I know, varargs are nothing more than arrays with a shorter syntax, and are not convertible to `Collection`s (so that's why this made me puzzled)...

Does anybody know how the magic works?

Thank you!

Comment: It's not using the `java.util.ArrayList`. There is an internal class in `Arrays` that's also called `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong `ArrayList` class. The one used in `Arrays.asList(..)` is `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` and has a constructor that accepts an array.

Answer (score 5):

The `ArrayList` type that's described here is not `java.util.ArrayList`; it's a private type defined inside that file (see line 3799). That one *does* have an array constructor, and it's the one referenced by `Arrays.asList`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! What a big trap!!! Sorry that the accepted answer goes to the quickest response... +1

Answer (score 4):

`Arrays.asList(...)` returns a new `ArrayList`. Here's the tricky part. The *new* `ArrayList` is not the one in the `java.util` package, it is actually a `static inner class` in `Arrays` class. Check this code.

**Arrays.java**

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
return new ArrayList<T>(a);
}
// the static inner class is shown below.
private static class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
implements RandomAccess, java.io.Serializable
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = -2764017481108945198L;
private final E[] a;

ArrayList(E[] array) {
        if (array==null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
    a = array;
}
```

...
   }

Comment: Thanks! What a big trap!!! Sorry that the accepted answer goes to the quickest response... +1